# Reading and storing only selected columns in a matrix using R

Tags: r, matrix, input

I have a text file with 7 columns and 120 rows. I want to only store the first 5 columns in a matrix.The columns are not named.I tried:

```
X <- as.matrix(read.table(filename, col.names=c("v1","v2",..."v7"))
```

> Error: unexpected symbol in:
>   "col.names=c("V1","V2","V3","V4","V5"))

How do I achieve my intended goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
X <- as.matrix(read.table(filename)[,1:5])
```

Comment: The only problem is this will read the whole table first, then subset it (of course this is not a big problem in this particular example).

Answer (score 3):

We can use `fread` from `data.table` and use the `select` option to read only the columns that is needed.  After that, we can convert to `matrix` (`as.matrix`).

```
 library(data.table)
 as.matrix(fread(filename, select=1:5))
```

Comment: Is there a library called data.table? I am unable to find it.

Comment: @204 Yes, there is one.  You can install it by `install.packages("data.table")`